# Coldfusion 11 CFHTMLTOPDF adding page break between 2 divs with position:relative

Tags: coldfusion, wkhtmltopdf, coldfusion-11

I am trying to create a pdf with `cfhtmltopdf` which contains 2 rows of divs which have a css setting of `position:relative;` . Between each row I want to have a page break which I create with `<cfhtmltopdfitem type="pagebreak" />`.

This creates the page break and adds the second row to the second page, however the second row is still included on the first page (so it is now duplicated). If you remove the `position:relative` it fixes the issue but breaks my formatting.

I have tried wrapping the code in another div or a table which doesn't contain `position:relative;` but I have found that if this content (divs,tables) has an object with a relative position then the same issue occurs. Does anyone have a work around for this? Example code is below.

```
<cfhtmltopdf orientation="landscape">
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>        
        <style>
            .block{width: 288px; height: 255px; margin: 0 0 10px 8px;position:relative;padding: 0; display:inline-block; top: 0; left:0; vertical-align:top;background: #cee7f4;color: #0081C6;}
            .block2{width: 288px; height: 255px; margin: 0 0 10px 8px;padding: 0; top: 0; left:0; vertical-align:top;background: #cee7f4;color: #0081C6;display:inline-block;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position:static;display:block;border:1px solid green;">test1
            <div class="block">
                Block 1
            </div>

            <div class="block">
                Block 2
            </div>

        </div>

        <cfhtmltopdfitem type="pagebreak" />

        <div style="position:static;display:block;border:1px solid red;">test 2
            <div class="block">
                Block 3
            </div>

            <div class="block">
                Block 4
            </div>

        </div>

        <cfhtmltopdfitem type="pagebreak" />        

        <div>This code works</div>

        <div class="block2">
            Block 5
        </div>

        <div class="block2">
            Block 6
        </div>

        <cfhtmltopdfitem type="pagebreak" />    
        <div class="block2">
            Block 7
        </div>

        <div class="block2">
            Block 8
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
</cfhtmltopdf>
```

Comment: You tagged "WKHTMLTOPDF" so I thought I'd try using that and it worked. I added "page-break-before:always" when I wanted to use a page break and it resulted in the second row being properly rendered on the second page.  I'm not sure why CFHTMLTOPDF doesn't work. (I've chosen to use WKHTMLTOPDF w/ColdFusion 9, 10 & 11 now as it works better & provides consistent results.)

Comment: @JamesMoberg I ended up switching to WKHTMLTOPDF as well as it doesn't appear the Coldfusion bug will be fixed quickly. The coldfusion team have passed the problem to the Acrobat team. [BugBase](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3791543)